# Error during Android Execution on device

Tags: android-activity

I am new to programming. Please bear with me. I tried developing spinner class on an existing activity with other views. However due to some error, the execution failed. I deleted all stuffs related to spinner class in

- activitymain.java
- main_activity.xml (in my case different name, this for easier
  understanding)

and every other detail related to spinner view

Now, when I am trying to execute the activity with existing views, I am getting the following error. Still not getting a hint of what happened and how this can be resolved

So here's what the logcat is displaying

```
02-14 04:41:29.341  20105-20105/com.example.bharathduraiswamy.comboedittext E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bharathduraiswamy.comboedittext/com.example.bharathduraiswamy.comboedittext.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.bharathduraiswamy.comboedittext.MainActivity
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2239)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.bharathduraiswamy.comboedittext.MainActivity
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity lacks default (with no parameters) constructor or throws some exception in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i am good. Overcame the errors and got the reason behind the error. Defined mainactivity.java as abstract but abstract classes can't be instantiated.

I believe the abstract was created when trying to implement onItemSelectListener() and I failed to delete it when deleting everything related to spinner view

Regards